# How to detect dead processes on android

Tags: android, process, task

I'm writing an app to do some logging on android, processes aren't killed as is the android way.

Can I detect which ones are dead though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29), then look for those with [`IMPORTANCE_EMPTY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html#IMPORTANCE_EMPTY).

Comment: Oh, OK I did this ... I guess my code must be wrong somewhere.

Comment: I ran the browser and then quit it, but even if I filter out IMPORTANCE_EMPTY it's still there, so I guess there is something else ?  [EDIT - I am a plumb]

Comment: OK, it looks like I also needed to check for IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND too.

Comment: Depends what you mean by “dead”, but yes. In particular, when you press the back button, the browser does not finish its activity but simply hides its task.

Comment: Actually, it seems that processes like to stay in BACKGROUND for a while.